# Bayesian hypothesis test: Type I and II errors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, inference

In a Bayesian hypothesis test between two alternatives A and B, what is the probability of making a type I and type II error?

This question has been asked many times on this forum in various formats: Is Bayesian hypothesis testing immune to peaking? What is the optimal stopping point? If the Bayes factor is more reliable than p-values, can we completely trust it? 
In this [paper](https://alexdeng.github.io/public/files/continuousMonitoring.pdf) Deng provides a strategy to stop early through FDR control and states that Bayesian testing does not provide type I error control based on simulation studies.

However, I do feel that the only way to clarify those questions and make Bayesian hypothesis testing more mainstream is to provide a solid argument against a frequentist concern namely type I and type II errors through a mathematical formula.

Consider the following situation: In a Bayesian hypothesis test between two alternatives A and B, what is the probability of making a type I and type II error?

Consider the following situation:

The posterior distribution is given by rebeta(z+a,N-z+b), where the posterior probability of A is rbeta(z0+a,N-z+b) and the posterior probability of B is rbeta(z1+a,N-z+b). Both have a Bernoulli likelihood and a beta-distributed prior.

- What is the type I and II error after the first test? after the nth test?